# Will this free all my **pointer memory?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to deallocate a **pointer if it already had something allocated at the end of a program. Is this the proper way to do it? 
The pointer is in another function with argument (char ***mena).
It seems to work, because when I try to print the values after, the program crashes. I just want to make sure.

```
int n(FILE *file, char ***mena,int already){
 //var declaration

  if (already) {
          for (i=0;i<already;i++)
            free((*mena)[i]);

          free(*mena);
          *mena=NULL;
     }
// function continues.....
```

Comment: Cannot know how to free if we don't know how it was allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is hard to tell, because it depends on the way these pointers were allocated.

But, as you have pointers 3 levels deep, I suppose it is not enough to free them.

You should have a look at tools like `valgrind` which helps you to identify memory leaks.

To explain a bit, `char ***` means that you have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a char. That means that the pointer points to a region of memory which can be allocated statically or dynamically. The same holds for all other levels.

You have to `free()` exactly those levels which were created dynamically, i. e. via `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` or `strdup()`.

Comment: I see- I think I know what you mean. I will have to clear each [i][j] subblock, then each [i] block and then the whole pointer to make it 100%... I think I understand thanks :)